# Linked List and the constructor

Tags: c++

I've been writing a code for my linked list project using C++. this is my code so far

Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct song1
{
    string song;
    string title;
    song1* next;
};
class song_list
{
protected:
    song1* head;
    int length;
public:
    song_list();
    bool insertSong (song1* newSong, int track);
    //bool removeSong (int track);
    void printSong();
    ~song_list();
};
song_list::song_list()
{
    head->song = "No data";
    head->title = "No data";
    head->next = NULL;
    length = 0;
}
bool song_list::insertSong (song1* newSong, int track)
{
    int count=0;
    if ((track<=0) || (track>length+1))
    {
        cerr<<"\nThe given track is out of range";
        return false;
    }
    if (head->next == NULL)
    {
        head->next= newSong;
        length++;
        return true;
    }
    count =0;
    song1* p = head;
    song1* q = head;
    while (q)
    {
        if (count==track)
        {
            p->next = newSong;
            newSong-> next = q;
            length++;
            return true;
        }
        p=q;
        q=p->next;
        count++;
    }
    if (count==track)
    {
        p->next = newSong;
        newSong-> next = q;
        length++;
        return true;
    }
    cerr<<"Song was not added in the list";
    return false;
}
void song_list::printSong()
{
    int count = 0;
    song1* p=head;
    song1* q=head;
    cout<<"\n------------------\n";
    cout<<"Song playlist\n";
    while (q)
    {
        p = q;
        cout<<"\n------------------\n";
        cout<<"\tPosition "<<count<<endl;
        cout<<"\tsong "<<p->title<<endl;
        cout<<"\tArtist "<<p->song<<endl;
        q= p->next;
        count++;
    }
}
song_list::~song_list()
{
    song1* p= head;
    song1* q=head;
    while (q)
    {
        p = q;
        q = p->next;
        if (q) delete p;
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedListh.h"
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int choice,repeat,trc;
    song1* info;
    song_list func;
    do
    {
    cout<<"1. Add song "<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Delete song "<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Show song "<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Search song "<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
            cout<<endl<<"Artist: ";
            getline (cin,info->song);
            //getline (cin,info->song);
            cout<<endl<<"Song Title: ";
            getline (cin,info->title);
            cout<<"Song number: "<<endl;//ask the user to put the song number
            //if artist doesnt exist the user should put 1.
            //else user should put what number the song is.
            cin>>trc;
            func.insertSong(info,trc);
        break;
    case 3:
        func.printSong();
        break;
    }
    cout<<"Repeat? 1.Yes 2.No"<<endl;
    cin>>repeat;
    }while (repeat == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The code can be build successfully but when i run the program, it show the "has stopped working" message. I figure out the error is in my constructor. Is that the correct way to initialize string? because if I erase the constructor, a message saying "song and title need to be initialize first" came out. I am still new in C++ so i am learning linked list bit by bit. By the way, am I doing the linked list correctly?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Info is an unassigned pointer when you try to populate its song member.

```
song1* info;


getline (cin,info->song);
```

You need to actually allocate memory for the pointer before you try to dereference it.

Or maybe you just meant:

```
song1 info;
```

and then just change the `->` to a `.` as in `info.song`.

That said, you almost certainly have other problems, as well.

Comment: `song_list` member `head` has a similar problem

Comment: I was trying to allocate memory of song1 using the constructor. but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: the constructor is called when you say "new ClassName()" or something similar.   song1* info = new song1(); would call the constructor to allcoate memory.   Though, smart pointers are usually preferred to doing the allcoation yourlsef (std::make_unique<song1>();)

Answer (score 0):

you can not attach data to variable head->song before you did not allocate memory.

Compiler does not occuring error while building, this error give at runtime.

```
song_list::song_list()
{
    head = new song1; // you have forgetten this line
    head->song = "No data";
    head->title = "No data";
    head->next = NULL;
    length = 0;
}
```

and song1* info is same way. you need to allocate memory

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already you need to allocate memory using the `new` operator. As it is, you have a pointer that points to its type only. A side note about the design: Would it be better to utilize your `struct` within the class? This way in main you are only dealing with the class and it's public members. Let your class construct the list.

Comment: will it be easier? sorry i only started learn data structure few days ago...although i've use C++ before but this class thingy is a completely new thing for me :)

Comment: I'm learning this as well. I was trying to say that your struct should be constructed by the list class. I have a similar post here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/125323/73806

Answer (score 0):

You have been missing a lot of error checking. Need to optimize or change the design of the Class song_list a lot.
No problem, Stay cool, As you have started learning just now. Kudos for your effort.

Just do allocate memory for head using the constructor of song_list

by modifying the code to

```
song_list::song_list()
{
    head = new song1;
    head->song = "No data";
    head->title = "No data";
    head->next = NULL;
    length = 0;
}
```

Then try to allocate memory for info on the main function

```
int main ()
{
    int choice,repeat,trc;
    song1* info;
    song_list func;
    info = new info;
```

.......

There is a memory leak here

```
song_list::~song_list()
{
    song1* p= head;
    song1* q=head;
    while (q)
    {
        p = q;
        q = p->next;
        if (q) delete p; // what happens for the last element if you check lastnode->next (would be null). the memory is lost.
    }
}
```